# Local upload file via rest web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, upload, jersey

I am using the code in this link http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/  to upload  a file.In this example I have to pass from a html page to specify the file to upload but I want to to acceed to it when I call the webservice by its path ( s.thing like that : http://*********:8080/RESTfulExample/file/upload/C://image.png)
Are there any suggestions to this issue? Please help!
That is what i did till now to solve it

```
@Path(value="/files")
public class upload {
@POST
@Path(value = "upload/{path}")
@Consumes("image/jpg")
public Response uploadPng(@PathParam("path") String path, File file) throws IOException     {
    file = new File("path");
    String uploadedFileLocation = "C:/Users/Desktop/" + file.getName();
    DataInputStream diStream =new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    long len = (int) file.length();
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int) len];
    int read = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (read < fileBytes.length && (numRead =
            diStream.read(fileBytes, read,fileBytes.length - read)) >= 0) {
        read = read + numRead;
    }
    writeToFile(diStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    System.out.println("File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation);
    return Response.status(200).entity(file).build();
  }
  private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                         String uploadedFileLocation) {
    try {
        OutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}}
```

But I have an 405 error now !!

**EDIT**

```
@Path(value= "/up")
public class upload {
private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER =    "C://Users/Marwa/Desktop/mafile.png";
@POST
@Path(value="upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream) {
    String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER ;
    System.out.println("*****serverpath********");
    saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);
    String output = "File saved to server location : " + filePath;
    return output;
}
 private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String serverLocation) {
    try {
    OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);}
        outpuStream.flush();
        outpuStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I need help !! Any one to answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd just call `http://example.com/file/upload` and post the file there with the browser (with JavaScript) or some other client. For example, you could test it with curl

```
curl -i -F "file=@/home/user1/Desktop/test.jpg" http://example.com/file/upload
```

Do you need the file path for something on the server side? If you need the path on the server side for some reason, you could just add a `@PathParam`.

```
@POST
@Path("/upload/{path}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @PathParam("path") String path, 
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    ...
}
```

You could also try leaving off `@consumes` or using a specific type like `@consumes("image/jpg")`. For example:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload/{path}")
@Consumes("image/jpg")
public Response uploadFile(
    @PathParam("path") String path, 
    InputStream uploadedInputStream) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But here @jcragun ( the last example ) what is uploadedInputStream ?

Comment: That's the actual file - a stream of bytes.

Comment: I edited my post so you can see my code . Plz check it @jcragun

Comment: You are posting a `png` but only allowing `jpg`. Try `@Consumes("image/png")`.

Comment: Still no luck? I tried running the example and got a "Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type" error.

Comment: I changed the method of work !! I edited my  post so you can see how it is now.The file to upload is added by a Client.